# How can I correct the syntax error in this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

```
delimiter //


DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS DIAGNOSIS; //  
CREATE PROCEDURE DIAGNOSIS(IN SYM INT, IN DISE VARCHAR(255))  

BEGIN  
 DECLARE I INT DEFAULT 1;  
 DECLARE SYM_COL VARCHAR(50);    
 DECLARE N INT DEFAULT 1;  
 DECLARE C INT DEFAULT 1;  
 DECLARE ST VARCHAR(255);  
 DECLARE DID INT;  
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SYM_TEMP (SID INT, SNAME VARCHAR(50));  
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE DISE_TEMP (DID INT, DNAME VARCHAR(100));  
--error stating problem with syntax!!!  
 IF DISE = '' THEN  
  SET SYM_COL = (SELECT SNAME FROM SYMPTOMS WHERE SID = SYM);  
--other set of codes  
 END IF;  
END//  
delimiter ;
```

Comment: why your are using ";" while you changed the delimiter to //
remove semicolon

Comment: @SLaks,I am taking about this line "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS DIAGNOSIS; //"

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon from the DROP PROCEDURE statement as delimiter has been changed
something like this:

```
delimiter //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS DIAGNOSIS //  
CREATE PROCEDURE DIAGNOSIS(IN SYM INT, IN DISE VARCHAR(255))      
BEGIN  
 DECLARE I INT DEFAULT 1;  
 DECLARE SYM_COL VARCHAR(50);    
 DECLARE N INT DEFAULT 1;  
 DECLARE C INT DEFAULT 1;  
 DECLARE ST VARCHAR(255);  
 DECLARE DID INT;  
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SYM_TEMP (SID INT, SNAME VARCHAR(50));  
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE DISE_TEMP (DID INT, DNAME VARCHAR(100));  
--error stating problem with syntax!!!  
 IF DISE = '' THEN  
  SET SYM_COL = (SELECT SNAME FROM SYMPTOMS WHERE SID = SYM);  
--other set of codes  
 END IF;  
END//  
delimiter ;
```

and I believe other code are good

Comment: Instead of saying "Try this" along with a code dump, you should at least point out *what* you changed.

Comment: I agree, have made an edit, will take-care. Thanks